# How to change the value of input number when another input number is changed

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have two input type number

```
 <input type="number" min="-100" max="5" [formControl]="maxNegative"/>

<input type="number" min="-100" max="5" [formControl]="maxNegative"/>
```

these two inputs are with the same formControl
I expected that while one input changed the second one would get its value, but it's not the case the second one doesn't have been changed

in js I have tried the following;

```
maxNegative = new FormControl(0);

 this.maxNegative.valueChanges.pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe((maxNegative) => {
     alert(maxNegative);
     this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
```

Comment: did you change your changeDetectionStrategy to OnPush? That would be one common way to explain this behaviour

Comment: Can you explain what you try to achieve? Because having multiple inputs bound to the same formControl seems highly unorthodox

Comment: yes i have changeDetectionStrategy OnPush, and i need that two inputs will have the same value 
I can change each one of them and the second suppose to be with the same value

Comment: I expect them to have the same value but your view doesn't represent that, since the changeDetection did not detect a Change in the I/O variables, therefore your view is not calculated anew.

Answer (score 0):

Using set value should set the value for both inputs, and use emitEvent to avoid a loop

```js
this.maxNegative.valueChanges.subscribe((maxNegative) => {
  this.maxNegative.setValue(maxNegative, {emitEvent: false})
});
```